# Changing the font size of an onHover label in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am working with chart.js to develop a graph. I have been able to change the title, axis and legend font size, but I haven't been able to change the font size of the label that appears when I hover over the graph (which came as default).

My code for that specific graph looks like this:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['Mouse (97.8 %)', 'Human (2.2 %)'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [1747649, 39589],
      label: 'Nº observations', // THIS IS THE ONE I WANT TO CHANGE
      backgroundColor: ['#F7DC6F', '#E59866'],
      borderWidth: 0.5
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        bottom: 20
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Expression data distribution by organism',
        font: {
          family: "Anek Latin",
          size: 35
        }

      },
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'top',
        labels: {
          font: {
            family: "Anek Latin",
            size: 25 // THIS FONT SIZE CORRESPONDS TO THE LABEL THAT APPEARS OUTSIDE OF THE GRAPH
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I haven't found anything in the Chart.js documentation, everything I find there and online relates to the font size of the legends that go outside the pie chart, not the one that appears on hovering.

I would appreciate if anyone knows how to change it.

Thank you!

Comment: add a hover object inside the plugins object in your chart options and set the mode to 'index' to enable the tooltip on hover. Then you can set the font size of the tooltip label by adding a bodyFont object and specifying the size property.

Comment: See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html for the tooltip options